# jq filter- unexpected "null"s

Tags: json, jq

input json:

```
{
  "id": 381,
  "name": "Module",
  "value": "C-A",
  "locked": false
}
{
  "id": 381,
  "name": "Module",
  "value": "",
  "locked": false
}
{
  "id": 381,
  "name": "Module",
  "value": "",
  "locked": false
}
```

And I want to remove all objects with value unset `""`
I have such filter but it prints also `null` - how to rid it of?

```
$ jq 'del(select(.value == ""))' /tmp/intest
{
  "id": 381,
  "name": "Module",
  "value": "C-A",
  "locked": false
}
null
null
```

update:
I want also to join non-empty values but get error:

```
$ jq 'select(.value!="")|.value|join(",")' /tmp/intest
jq: error (at /tmp/intest:6): Cannot iterate over string ("C-A")
```

Comment: `del/1` is not meant to be used that way. You would use it to remove certain properties from objects or arrays, but not to remove a result itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just revert the logic:

```
jq 'select(.value!="")'
```

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using `del` at all in this case. It's not really meant to be used like this.

Comment: I agree. Removed it